# Application runs on eclipse emulator, but not others

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm new to android app development but I've successfully created my first real application in eclipse. It runs perfectly in the eclipse emulator so I compiled it and tried to install it on another emulator. It installs successfully, but won't run at all. I'm not even sure how to begin finding the error since everything works so well in eclipse. Can someone refer me to a resource to help me start troubleshooting the problem. I think it might have something to do with the compilation, but I just don't know.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you see that it installs on the second emulator but doesn't run? If it installs, it cannot be a compilation error, cause with a compile error, it won't install.
So, if it installs on the device, you should see the app icon if you press the menu icon on the emulator and then you should be able to start it by clicking on that icon.

To track down the error, you should use DDMS in Eclipse or command line:
adb shell logcat
The adb tool is in the tools folder of the Android SDK.

Comment: did u check the minimum sdk version in the manifest file?